# How to prevent input fields from stretching beyond it's parent's width on small devices?

Tags: html, css, forms, stretching

I have the following:

```css
form {
 border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
      <p>
        <label> Your name<br>
          <span>
            <input name="your-name" value="" size="40" type="text">
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Your telephone<br>
          <span>
            <input name="your-tel" value="" size="40" type="tel">
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Your email<br>
          <span>
            <input name="your-email" value="" size="40" type="email">
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Subject<br>
          <span>
            <input name="your-subject" value="" size="40" type="text">
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Attachments<br>
          <span>
            <input name="your-file" size="40" type="file">
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label> Your message<br>
          <span>
            <textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" ></textarea>
          </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input value="Send" type="submit">
      </p>
    </form>
```

The CSS is just to help visualizing the error, which is: on small screens (320x480) the `<input>`s stretch beyond the form boundaries. Considering that I can't change the HTML, how can I prevent this?

For instance, I tried inserting "max-width: inherit" in each `<label>`, `<span>` and `<input>`, and then setting the `<p>` `max-width` to 200px, which worked like a charm, but obviously would impact the layout on larger screens. I then tried changing this `max-width` to 100%, but it just became the same as before.

Comment: `max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;` works good with me .. as you need to consider border and padding

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried it, but with padding things break again.

Comment: so show un the full code then .. as with your actual code it works fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's a production webpage with lots  and lots of CSS... I'll try to make this snippet more like the real code, but to simply dumping it all here would be really hard. I'll do it in a couple hours.

Comment: @Metalcoder Why do you have html attribute size?

Answer (score -2):

Try this, although you should maybe name your form

```
<form name="FormName" form action="#" method="post">

</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
    max-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: My code is just a simplification from the original issue, so I removed it's name to avoid cluttering. Anyways, Firefo dev tools complains that the `auto` value is invalid.